# Read and add multiple numbers on different console lines

Tags: c#, console

Just standard programming practice, I'm trying to figure out a way an efficient way to get console input and add it all together on multiple lines.

For instance input can be like this...

20 20 20 20 20 20

20 20 20 20 20 20

This doesn't become a problem until I reach the newline. In which it becomes 2020, which isn't right.

```
    string equation = "";
    string line = "";

    while (line != null)
    {
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        equation += line;

    }

    string[] splits = equation.Split(' ');
    int[] numbers = splits.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    int result = 0;
    foreach (int i in numbers)
    {
        result += i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Why not doing `equation += (equation == "") ? line : " " + line;`?

Comment: Looks to be because you're not stripping out any carriage return.

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo I didn't think to use ternary operators. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just evaluate each line immediately after input:

```
int result = 0;

while (true)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
        break;
    }

    result += line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(int.Parse)
                  .Sum();
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about .Sum() Thanks!